# What does Matthew 12:6 mean?

Tags: matthew, jesus, new-testament, christianity

What does Matthew 12:6 mean? Is Jesus Christ referring to himself or 'something' else? I mean the sacrifice of Jesus Christ.

> Matt 12:6 - But I tell you that something greater than the temple is
> here.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably two referents in Jesus' comment in matt 12:6.  The first is the Messianic prophecy in Hag 2:9 -

> The latter glory of this house will be greater than the former, says
> the LORD of Hosts. And in this place I will provide peace, declares
> the LORD of Hosts.”

I believe that in Matt 12:6 Jesus also refers to His remark in John 2:19-21 -

> Jesus answered, “Destroy this temple, and in three days I will raise
> it up again.” “This temple took forty-six years to build,” the Jews
> replied, “and You are going to raise it up in three days?” **But Jesus
> was speaking about the temple of His body**.

Thus, Jesus referring to Himself as noted by most commentators.  Note the remarks of Ellicott -

> The passage thus referred to furnishes obviously the true explanation
> of our Lord’s assertion of His greatness here, and spoken, as it
> probably was, to scribes from Jerusalem, may have been intended to
> remind them of it. The body of the Son of Man was the truest, highest
> temple of God, and the disciples who ministered to Him were entitled
> to at least the same privilege as the priests in the Temple at
> Jerusalem.

Meyer is more detailed in his reasoning:

> **Matthew 12:6**. As in Matthew 12:3 f. Jesus had reasoned a majori (from the fact of David, when hungry, being allowed to eat the
> shew-bread) ad minus (to the fact of the hungry disciples being
> allowed to pluck the corn on the Sabbath), so in Matthew 12:5 He
> reasons a minori (viz. from the temple, where the Sabbath is
> subordinated to the sacrificial arrangements) ad majus, viz. to His
> own authority, which transcends the sanctity of the temple, and from
> acting under which the disciples might well be the less disposed to be
> bound to keep the Sabbath. The key to this argument is to be found in
> Matthew 12:6, which contains the minor proposition of the conclusion:
> what is allowable in the case of the servants of the temple, namely,
> to work on the Sabbath, must be conceded to the servants of Him who is
> greater than the temple; I am greater than the temple; therefore, and
> so on.

Comment: +1 -- 

Matthew 12:6

One greater than the temple (του ἱερου μειζον [tou hierou meizon]). Ablative of comparison, του ἱερου [tou hierou]. The Textus Receptus has μειζων [meizōn], but the neuter is correct. Literally, “something greater than the temple.” What is that? It may still be Christ, or it may be: “The work and His disciples were of more account than the temple” (Plummer). “If the temple was not subservient to Sabbath rules, how much less the Messiah!” (Allen).
 -- 

Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (Mt 12:6). Nashville, TN: Broadman Press.

Comment: *14 Καὶ ὁ λόγος σὰρξ ἐγένετο καὶ ἐσκήνωσεν ἐν ἡμῖν,* καὶ ἐθεασάμεθα τὴν δόξαν αὐτοῦ, δόξαν ὡς μονογενοῦς παρὰ πατρός, πλήρης χάριτος καὶ ἀληθείας.  ...  ⸀ὅτι ἐκ τοῦ πληρώματος αὐτοῦ ἡμεῖς πάντες ἐλάβομεν καὶ χάριν ἀντὶ χάριτος·* 17 ὅτι ὁ νόμος διὰ Μωϋσέως ἐδόθη,* ἡ ⸀χάρις καὶ ἡ ἀλήθεια διὰ Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ ἐγένετο. *18 Θεὸν οὐδεὶς ἑώρακεν πώποτε·* ⸂μονογενὴς θεὸς⸃ ὁ ὢν εἰς τὸν κόλπον τοῦ πατρὸς ἐκεῖνος ἐξηγήσατο⸆. 
(John 1:14,16–18, NA28)

Comment: Is there any connection between Matthew 12:6 and Hag 2:9?

Comment: @Tijo - YES - Jesus is referring to Haggai's prophecy which was fulfilled By Jesus in Matt 12:6.